# Change a virtual machine Notes attributes in esxi shell

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtualization

I have tried to change via ESXi shell the attribute field with the following command:

```
vmx -s attributes=new notes /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/VM/VM.vmx
```

but it doesn't change the attributes and doesn't give me any error. 
Is there any command to do that?

I am using ESXi 5.0,

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [PowerCLI](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?productId=285&downloadGroup=VSP510-PCLI-510).

```
Connect-VIServer esxihost.example.com
Set-VM name-of-vm -Notes "Here are some notes"
```

Comment: Can i set it without a power CLI ? In Esxi shell

Comment: You shouldn't be using that shell for routine tasks as a general rule. You should only be messing around with the shell if asked to do so by VMware support.